# Populating my drop down list C# asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am trying to get a drop down list to display data from MYSQL database, database table name is Pet and I am trying to get the information from Specie.
Now the code looks good to me but it is not running so its always best to get another pair of eyes to look over it.
Thanks, 
All help is appreciated. 
**connection string**

```
   MySqlConnection cs = new MySqlConnection(@"Data Source = 000.000.00.000;username=benoatsc_admin;password=****; Initial Catalog = dbname; Integrated Security = true");
```

**drop down code**

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlCommand cd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Pet", cs);
        cs.Open();
        MySqlDataReader ddl = cd.ExecuteReader();

        DdPetList.DataSource = ddl;
        DdPetList.DataValueField = "Specie";
        DdPetList.DataTextField = "Specie";
        DdPetList.DataBind();
        cs.Close();
        cs.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: What does "not running" mean (error message, behavior, logs...)? Please be specific. Also, when do you want this code to run?

Comment: sorry, what I mean is my program runs, but the drop down list is not populated with any data it is blank.

Comment: WHEN do you want the list to be populated? If it is when you load the page, you are using the wrong method.

Comment: SJuan76, thank you very much! always is the simplest problem that cause so much stress, so simple when you here it from another, thanks again.

Comment: Yes you should use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

1. You should likely move this code to the `Page_Load` method. I would assume that you want this `DropDownList` populated when the page loads for the user. Otherwise, the `DropDownList` is never populated with the data from your MySQL Database, hence you will not be able to trigger the `SelectedIndexChanged` event when there is no index to possibly change.
2. MySQL Connector/Net makes use of [unmanaged resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/498928w2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). These should be **disposed** of when they are finished being used. The .NET Framework offers an elegant way to ensure that objects utilizing unmanaged resources are disposed of in the form of **[using statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**. It is best practice to use them.
3. When `MySqlConnection`, `MySqlDataReader`, etc. should not only be disposed of when they are done being used, but they should also be **closed**. Thankfully, when `dispose()` is called on these objects their `close()` methods are called as well.

So piecing this all together yields this piece of code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(/* Your connection string here */))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Pet", conn))
        {
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    DropDownList1.DataSource = reader;
                    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Specie";
                    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Specie";
                    DropDownList1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this all helps. If you need any clarifications, I will gladly provide it.

Comment: Hi Derek, thank you very much your answer has been very informative, I will make the adjustments to my program now.

Comment: Thing is, I have my connection string called in my `public partial class _Default : Page` due to the fact that I have used it in a data grid view and input via text box.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a comment but i don't have the reputation,

what error message are you receiving ?

your connection string has got both trusted connection set to true and you are providing credentials, 
remove one of them.

Comment: thanks for the advice on the CS. have removed one. with regards to my problem the program runs, its just the drop down list is not populated with any-data.

Comment: to state the obvious are you definitely getting data? IE if you breakpoint after execute reader and examine the contents of ddl, also check your column names ? and possibly swap your datavaluefield and datatextfield order (a bit absurd but its happened to me)

Comment: is working, had it in wrong class. have moved to pageload class, thanks for your help.

Comment: great news, anytime :)

Comment: Page_Load is a **method** and not a **class**.